# php code for inserting text file into the database

Tags: php, mysql, filefield

hey i have form which has a file field. After selecting a file,i want to insert the selected file into the database column. how do i do it?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend using the database for files content because the database is limited when it comes to this.  Sure there are `text` fields that you can put the content into, but even those are limited to a certain degree.  In any case, the `text` field type is being deprecated in the future.  I would get into the habit of trying to stay away from it, unless you really need to have it.  You can just as easily open up the content when needed, using [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [`fgets`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), [`fclose`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).  Or [`fread`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), or [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of storing it into the database, why not store it as a file on the server, using [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

However, just noticing that maybe you are referring to the file name being stored in the database, if so than that would work great and use a varchar(255) should be perfectly fine.

In this case, make sure to have a method="post" and an action="whatever.php" for the form set.  And `ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data"`. Than a normal submit button will trigger the action and you can handle it directly from there.  You can use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to store it within a path on the server, or if it's a text file and you need to do some editing to it, one of the methods I mentioned above should do it.  Otherwise, to get the file from a form, use the [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) predefined PHP Array.  You'll want to get the `$_FILES['file_input_name']['tmp_name']` and `$FILES['file_input_name']['name']` values, where `file_input_name` = the name attribute for the  tag for your file input within the form.

Answer (score 1):

Just 4 steps:

1. You have to setup the form correctly: add ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" in the form tag.
2. In your php page you have to [read the content of the file](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=upload+file+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)
3. Escape the binary data using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
4. Using a standard query put the file contents into you row.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the file is large you may want to make surre the column datatype is set to blob or something similar.